# C++, параметры метода по умолчанию

Tags: c++, параметры, класс

Я бы хотел узнать, есть ли разница в том, где именно указано, что параметр метода имеет значение по умолчанию? Компилятор позволяет указывать параметр по умолчанию либо в объявлении, либо в определении, но не сразу в двух местах.

Для чего это сделано?

Comment: Вообще-то указывать лучше в объявлении, чтоб о наличии такого параметра знали и другие, а не только тело функции... :)

Comment: То есть, если параметр по умолчанию указан в определении, то в другом файле, который подключает класс через хедер, не будет видно, что метод обладает параметром по умолчанию? На что это повлияет, и повлияет ли?

Comment: Как на что? вы просто не сможете не указать тот параметр, что по умолчанию...

Comment: Есть еще третий вариант - указывать в перегруженном методе. И четвертый - сделать функцию с произвольным количеством и порядком аргументов, из которых шаблоном собирать параметры.

Comment: @Harry, не совсем понял вас.

Comment: @MGNeo Параметр по умолчанию будет действовать только в одном .cpp файле (где реализован метод). В других местах нужно будет при вызове метода всегда указывать все параметры.